# Jquery - Selecting the correct class from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr id="item-1">
     <td class="shopping-cart-quantity">
         <div class="product-quantity">
            <input id="product-quantity" data-area="item-1" data-product="1" type="text" value="3">
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="item-2">
     <td class="shopping-cart-quantity">
         <div class="product-quantity">
            <input id="product-quantity" data-area="item-2" data-product="2" type="text" value="3">
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="item-3">
     <td class="shopping-cart-quantity">
         <div class="product-quantity">
            <input id="product-quantity" data-area="item-3" data-product="3" type="text" value="3">
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The input field uses Twitter Bootstrap Spin and the input id="product-quantity" renders as follows:

```
<div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin input-group-sm">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn quantity-down bootstrap-touchspin-down" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-prefix"></span>
    <input id="product-quantity" data-area="item-3" data-product="3" type="text" value="3" readonly="" class="form-control input-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-postfix"></span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn quantity-up bootstrap-touchspin-up" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

My goal is to grab the data-area value so that I can apply the correct quantities to the correct product however no matter what I do, it always returns the first item in the table.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('click','.input-group',function(){
        alert($('.input-group').find('#product-quantity').data("area"));
    });
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what the user is supposed to click on and what should happen when they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a click handler `this` is the actual element clicked:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('click','.input-group',function(){
        alert($(this).find('#product-quantity').data("area"));
    });
```

but the actual problem is having duplicate IDs. That is invalid HTML and jQuery can only see the first.

Replace `id="product-quantity"` with a class and use `.product-quantity`

Comment: Argh - thanks a stack, this solved the problem. Slowly coming to grips with JQuery!